# How to solve exponential equation with two variables?

Tags: python, math, scipy, scipy-optimize

### Background

I have one exponential equation like this:

```
a - b * np.exp(-c/x) - y * np.exp(-delta/x).sum() * 2
```

where a, b, and c are constants, the delta is a 1D array that is available from [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1stiAdKq3p-rEnIpr6LT3-EI3gDAZi5j-/view?usp=sharing). The goal is to solve the `x` and `y`.

### Attempt

To solve the equation with bounds, I come up with `optimize.minimize` to get the `x` and `y` where the square of residue is minimum.

Here's the full example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize as opt

a = 35167.7
b = 11919.5
c = 1.68
delta = np.load('delta.npy')

def residual_sum(x0, a, b, c, delta):
    x = x0[0]
    y = x0[1]

    residual = a - b * np.exp(-c/x) - y * np.exp(-delta/x).sum() * 2

    return residual**2

bnds = ((1, 24), (30, 1500))
x_init = 3
y_init = 300
x0 = [x_init, y_init]

solution = opt.minimize(residual_sum, x0, bounds=bnds, args=(a, b, c, delta))
print(solution['x'][0], solution['x'][1])
```

However, when I change the init values, the results are quite different:

```
solution = opt.minimize(residual_sum, [3, 300], bounds=bnds, args=(a, b, c, delta))
print(solution['x'][0], solution['x'][1])

solution = opt.minimize(residual_sum, [5, 500], bounds=bnds, args=(a, b, c, delta))
print(solution['x'][0], solution['x'][1])

Output:
10.110838104427442 87.90413009609203
24.0 80.08308172149127
```

### Problem

So, I check the equation with manual inputs of x and y:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 24, 200)
y = np.linspace(0, 1500, 500)

res = (a - b * np.exp(-c/x))[:, None] - np.exp(-delta[:,np.newaxis]/x).sum(axis=0)[:, None] * y * 2

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

m = ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, (res**2).T, cmap='viridis', norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm())

bnds = ((1, 24), (30, 1500))
x_init = 3
y_init = 300
x0 = [x_init, y_init]

solution = opt.minimize(residual_sum, x0, bounds=bnds, args=(a, b, c, delta))
ax.scatter(solution['x'][0], solution['x'][1], marker='*', facecolors='none', edgecolors='r')

plt.colorbar(m)
```

There's an obvious low-value line in the figure. Any idea how to get the "correct" solution?

[image: example]

Here's the same data with lower vmax:

```
m = ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, (res**2).T, cmap='viridis', vmax=2e3)
```

[image: example2]

Comment: "obvious low-value _line_ in the figure" - doesn't this mean there are infinitely many solutions?

Comment: @ForceBru Yes, that's my first thought. But, if I set `vmax=2e3` for that figure, there're few low values. Does that mean there should be a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation looks like this:

```
a - b * np.exp(-c/x) - y * np.exp(-delta/x).sum() * 2 = 0
```

Which is to say:

```
y = (a - b * np.exp(-c/x)) / np.exp(-delta/x).sum() / 2
```

You can plug any value for `x` and get the corresponding `y`:

```
>>> import numpy as np; import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> a,b,c = 35167.7, 11919.5, 1.68
>>> delta  = np.load('delta.npy')
>>> def the_y(x): return (a - b * np.exp(-c/x)) / np.exp(-delta/x).sum() / 2
... 
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> X = np.linspace(1, 24, 1000)
>>> plt.plot(X, [the_y(x) for x in X]); plt.show()
```

Here's the plot:

[image]

Indeed, for each `x` in `X = np.linspace(1, 24, 1000)` I got the corresponding `y` value. You could generate a bazillion of `x`s and get a bazillion of `y`s in response, so I'd say there are infinitely many solutions.